# One equation, three unknowns.

Tags: calculus

$\{ x,y,z \in\Bbb Z\ \}$ If $5x^2 + 5y^2 + z^2 + 4 = 4xy +4yz + 4x$

I assume that I should make this equation in a form like $(x...) + (y...) + (z...) = 0$. How should I do this? Tried to get everything somehow together, but I'm still failing.

I want to know all the decimal possibilities, for which this equation is true.

Comment: What's the actual problem, is there a question after the definition of your function

Comment: What are you trying to do with this equation?

Comment: Are you trying to isolate one variable?

Comment: Is there any mistake with degrees of $z$? May be $4yz^2$ instead of $4yz$? Of $z^2$ instead of $z^4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$5x^2 + 5y^2 + z^2 + 4 - 4xy  - 4yz - 4x =  (4y^2 - 4yz + z^2)  + ( 4x^2 - 4xy + y^2) + (x^2 - 4x + 4) = (2y - z)^2  + (2x - y)^2 + (x - 2)^2 = 0$$

Is it clear, what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

$5x^2+5y^2+z^2 -4xy - 4yz - 4x = -4$

Looks to me like the equation of an ellipse.  So the first thing I want to know is where is the center.

$\nabla (5x^2+5y^2+z^2 -4xy - 4yz - 4x) = \mathbf 0$ is a quick way to get there.

$10x + 4y  = 4\\-4x + 10y - 4z = 0\\ -4y + 2z = 0$

$(x,y,z) = 2,4,8$

and as it turns out

$5(2^2)+5(4^2)+(8^2) -4(2)(4) - 4(4)(8) - 4(2) = -4$

There is only one solution.