# When can a quadratic form in $n$ variables be written as the sum of $m$ squares?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

This question is inspired
by this one:

[One equation, three unknowns.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181228/one-equation-three-unknowns)

That question was to
find all integer solutions to
$5x^2 + 5y^2 + z^2 + 4 = 4xy +4yz + 4x$.

The key,
as noticed by 
Andrei Kulunchakov,
is that
$5x^2 + 5y^2 + z^2 + 4 - 4xy  - 4yz - 4x \\
=  (4y^2 - 4yz + z^2)  + ( 4x^2 - 4xy + y^2) + (x^2 - 4x + 4) \\
= (2y - z)^2  + (2x - y)^2 + (x - 2)^2 
$.

My question is a generalization,
restricted to quadratics:

Consider the quadratic equation
in $n$ variables
$f(x_1, ..., x_n)
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^2
+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} b_{ij}x_ix_j
+\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i
+d = 0
$.

When can $f$ be written in the form
$f(x_1, ..., x_n)
=\sum_{k=1}^m (\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}x_i+s_k)^2
$?

An obvious step
is to expand the terms
in the latter sum.

$\begin{array}\\
(\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}x_i+s_k)^2
&=(\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}x_i+s_k)(\sum_{j=1}^nr_{kj}x_j+s_k)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nr_{ki}r_{kj}x_ix_j
+s_k(\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}x_i+\sum_{j=1}^nr_{kj}x_j)+s_k^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}^2x_i^2
+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}r_{ki}r_{kj}x_ix_j
+2s_k\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ki}x_i+s_k^2\\
\end{array}\\
$

Summing these up
and equating the two representations,
we get the system of equations

$\begin{array}\\
a_i
&=\sum_{k=1}^m r_{ki}^2\\
b_{ij}
&=2\sum_{k=1}^m r_{ki}r_{kj}\\
c_i
&=2\sum_{k=1}^m s_kr_{ki}\\
d
&=\sum_{k=1}^m s_k^2
\end{array}
$

There are possibly
$2n+\frac12 n(n-1)+1
=\frac12(n^2-n+4n+2)
=\frac12(n^2+3n+2)
=\frac12(n+1)(n+2)
$
equations
in the variables
$r_{ki}$ and $s_k$.

The number of variables is
$mn+n = n(m+1)$,
so we seem to need
$\frac12(n+1)(n+2)
\ge n(m+1)
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
m
&\le \dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2n}-1\\
&= \dfrac{n^2+3n+2-2n}{2n}\\
&= \dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2n}\\
&= \dfrac{n+1}{2}+\dfrac1{n}\\
\end{array}
$

I'm not sure where 
to go from here,
so I'll leave it at this.

Comment: the way you write this, it is necessary that the homogeneous quadratic part have mixed coefficients even and an expression as $M = R^T R$ in integer matrices, therefore positive semidefinite

Comment: where was I...also local conditions. For example, $2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 6 z^2$ can be written as a sum of squares, but $x^2 + 3 y^2 + 3 z^2$ cannot, despite having square determinant. It is necessary that the quadratic part be isotropic in all $\mathbb Q_p$

Comment: Anyway, that is about m=n=3. Easier if you allow more squares.